# Get unique array of certain column of object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched and read many related questions here but I still can't figure it out.

I have a array of objects like:

```
 
{id: 1, size: 'small', weight: '1 kg', color: 'red', price: 100}
{id: 2, size: 'small', weight: '1 kg', color: 'blue', price: 200}
{id: 3, size: 'small', weight: '2 kg', color: 'green', price: 300}
{id: 4, size: 'small', weight: '2 kg', color: 'yellow', price: 400}
{id: 5, size: 'large', weight: '4 kg', color: 'pink', price: 500}
{id: 6, size: 'large', weight: '4 kg', color: 'navy blue', price: 600}
{id: 7, size: 'large', weight: '4 kg', color: 'cyan', price: 700}
{id: 8, size: 'large', weight: '6 kg', color: 'amber', price: 800}
{id: 9, size: 'large', weight: '6 kg', color: 'black', price: 900}
```

How can I get unique values of certain column?

for example for 'size' how can I get only 'small' and 'large' from this array? Not 4 'small' and 5 'large'

Is there a way to chain it after filtering below?

```
products.filter((p) => Object.keys(selected).every((k) => selected[k] === p[k]))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @gabriel-rodríguez-flores
could you please tell me how we can get and additional incremental id with each term? in way for example: {id:1 value:small} {id:2 value:large}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Set` to reduce to unique values:

```js
const sizeList = [ ...new Set(array.map(item => item.size)) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I'm doing this after filtering some products in:
products.filter((p) => Object.keys(selected).every((k) => selected[k] === p[k]))
is there a way to chain it after the filter?

Comment: product in [ ...new Set(products.filter((p) => Object.keys(selected).every((k) => selected[k] === p[k])).map(item => item[attribute.name]))]

It works!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: As long as I understand your question that doesn't make sense. After filter you are checking all keys, so every element should be the same, just take the first element after the filter and it's done, no need to reduce with Set

Comment: I'm trying to make related select menus that their values change based on available products, So I filter products base on key values in 'selected' (When you select an attribute it will go in selected so I filter every key and value in order to filter the desired products). I wanted to populate my attribute select menus and I got like: 4 small and 5 large instead of small and large, thats why I need to filter these